# Why are time derivatives of states in QFT equal to zero?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, hamiltonian, eigenvalue, quantum-states

In equation 6-38 on page 176 of the book "Student Friendly QFT" by Robert D. Klauber it is said that the partial derivative w.r.t. time of a multi-particle state is equal to zero since we are working in the Heisenberg picture: http://www.quantumfieldtheory.info/website_Chap02.pdf

How do we know that we are working in the Heisenberg picture?

Wo choose a classical Lagrangian, apply second quantisation, discover the numerical coefficients in the plane waves have become creation and annihilation operators and we get the Hamiltonian and momentum operators corresponding to the classical observables from relations in classical mechanics, with the fields and conjugate fields now promoted to operators.

At what point did we enter the Heisenberg picture?

Nowhere have we said anything about the presence of any $e^{-iHt}$ unitary time evolution operators...

Is the fact that the operators like ${\phi(x,t)}$ are time-dependent enough to conclude that there cannot be any time-dependence in the states?

Or does it have something to do with the fact it makes no difference since in elementary QFT
one only ever deals with energy eigenstates and therefore putting a $e^{-iHt}$ on one side of an operator and a $e^{-iHt}$ on the other makes no difference since they cancel out for energy eigenstates?

Comment: There's a lot of steps in the "apply second quantization" part. Choosing the definitions of the relevant operators is part of that, which also sets the choice of picture.

Comment: Does [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/561251/is-electric-field-operator-in-schrödinger-picture-time-dependent) shed light?

Answer (score 1):

The book pretty explicitly specifies when the operators are in the Schrodinger picture and when they're in the Heisenberg picture; for example, $H^S$ is the Schrodinger-picture Hamiltonian and $H$ is the Heisenberg-picture Hamiltonian.

In general, though, the choice of picture is also in principle arbitrary. We happen to do most QFT calculations in the interaction picture, simply because the expressions for the operators we're interested in are the simplest in that picture.

Comment: It does this at a point up to which the book has not done any second quantisation yet and  has not treated any QFT multi-particle states yet so it doesn't really tell you what it means to be working in a Heisenberg picture in QFT or why the states are time-independent. One question I have is: wouldn't you need to put $e^{-iHt}$ in places?

Comment: Come to think of it... A general quantum state in QFT is not time-independent. The field operator operator, for instance, acting on the vacuum gives a quantum state that is not constant in time since the field operator itself can depend on time. However states that consist only of time independent annihilation operators would be time independent if the vacuum state is time independent which sounds reasonable to me. This kind of quantum state is the one treated in the equation I referred to so this would be a satisfactory resolution for me. But is the vacuum state time independent and why?

Comment: @StijnBoshoven Let's go back to basic geometry for a moment: suppose you have two snapshots of a unit vector at two different moments in time. To get from one snapshot to the other, you can, for example, rotate the unit vector directly, while leaving the coordinate grid the same (this is an "active transformation"). But you could also leave the vector alone, and instead rotate the coordinate grid (this is a "passive transformation"). Or you could do some mix of both. All of these transformations have the same result, and you can freely choose which one to apply.

Comment: @StijnBoshoven This is analogous to the Schrodinger and Heisenberg pictures. The Schrodinger picture leaves the "coordinate grid" constant (i.e. the operators), while rotating the "vectors" (i.e. the states). The Heisenberg picture leaves the "vectors" (i.e. the states) where they are, but rotates the "coordinate grid" (i.e. the operators). They give you identical predictions, and you can freely choose which one suits you (or some other scheme, like the interaction picture).

Comment: The problem I have with the book is that it says "the time derivative of the state is zero because we are working in the Heisenberg picture" when the Heisenberg picture is defined that way so it's not really an explanation. Nowhere did we get to decide where we enter the Heisenberg picture or did the book explain what the alternative is and how that works precisely. I know what the different pictures are but I cant see it applied in a QFT context

Comment: @StijnBoshoven Maybe I'm looking in the wrong passage, but I'm not seeing the section you're mad about. Can you be more specific in the question as to which particular section you're talking about?